# Generating a point (vector/matrix) in OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

I'd like to create a [polyhedron](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#polyhedron) in [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) by generating its point [vector](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#Vectors)s programmatically. However, assigning a value to a matrix...

```
p = [1,0,0];
r = [[], [], [], [], [], [] ];

for( i=[0:5] ) 
{
    echo("i=",i);
    r[i] = [0,1];
}
```

... produces a syntax error:

```
ERROR: Parser error in line 7: syntax error 
ERROR: Compilation failed!
```

Am I making a mistake (which) or are these types really only read-only (no assignment by index)?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30272219/1619432)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to modify `r` after it was assigned.

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/List_Comprehensions for expressions that can generate lists.

Example:

```
points = [ for (a = [0 : 5 : 359]) [ 20 * sin(a), 10 * cos(a) ] ];
polygon(points);
```

Comment: I don't think your statement is quite true; see the answer linked in my comment to the question: `standard variables are set at compile-time in OpenSCAD, not run-time`. I'll give the list comprehension a try, though.

Comment: What part is not true? You can't modify `r`. It's possible to write multiple assignments but only the last one will actually be used (the reassignment should ideally be flagged as error, but that's not possible due to backward compatibility). Also note that the restriction mentioned in that linked answer is not there anymore. That code actually works fine as long as the cube dimensions are not negative.

Comment: I thought it could be reassigned a static value, but this does not work either.

Comment: How do use a variable in that for loop? For example if i want to modifiy a list of differential coordinates (dx,dy) into absolute coordinates, I would have a foor loop like this: pc = [0,0];
for (idx = [ 0 : len(points) - 1 ] ) 
{
    p = points[idx];
    pc = pc + p;
    p2[idx] = pc;
}

Comment: Same answer as before, you can't. Instead separately calculate the absolute coordinates based on the differential list, e.g. using a recursive function: to_abs = function(v,i = 0,p = [0, 0], r = [])
    i < len(v)
        ? let(p = p + v[i]) to_abs(v, i + 1, p, [each r, p])
        : r;